# React Material Components Web not working on live server

Tags: reactjs

i'm using https://react-mdc.github.io/#/ Layout Grid component along with http://www.material-ui.com/#/ components and on my local machine everything works fine, but when i deploy on a live server after `npm run build` react-mdc layout grid columns stack the wrong way. is there a correct way to import react-mdc components for them to work on a live server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I had to wrap my `<LayoutGrid.Cell>`'s with `<div className="mdc-layout-grid__inner"></div>` since this tag became necessary.